# Cumsum (sort of) in Pandas starting with negative or zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe one of my vars looks like this:

```
user, time, used
1, 2015-01-01, 0
1, 2015-02-01, 0
1, 2015-03-01, 0
1, 2015-04-01, 1
1, 2015-05-01, 0
2, 2015-01-01, 0
2, 2015-02-01, 1
2, 2015-03-01, 0
```

The "used" variable is basically an indicator that shows the first time that a user shows up. What I am trying to do is to create a new variable that indicates how many months before and after first use we are in like this:

```
user, time, used, new
1, 2015-01-01, 0, -3
1, 2015-02-01, 0, -2
1, 2015-03-01, 0, -1
1, 2015-04-01, 1, 0
1, 2015-05-01, 0, 1
2, 2015-01-01, 0, -1
2, 2015-02-01, 1, 0
2, 2015-03-01, 0, 1
```

I just can't think of a good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I see it's an old question but to do it in few lines and more efficiently, you can use `groupby`, `cumcount` and remove the position of row where 'used' is 1 with `transform` and `argmax` such as:

```
used_g = df.groupby('user')['used']
df['new'] = used_g.cumcount() - used_g.transform(lambda x: (x.values).argmax())
```

Then `df` looks like expected

```
   user         time  used  new
0     1   2015-01-01     0   -3
1     1   2015-02-01     0   -2
2     1   2015-03-01     0   -1
3     1   2015-04-01     1    0
4     1   2015-05-01     0    1
5     2   2015-01-01     0   -1
6     2   2015-02-01     1    0
7     2   2015-03-01     0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way. This way is **really** slow but it is what I landed on as it works.

```
df['test']=1
df.groupby('acctnum')['test'].cumsum()
df['new']=0
for acctnum in df['acctnum'].unique():
    df['test2']=df[df['acctnum']==acctnum].loc[::-1,'test'].cumsum()
    df['test3']=df[df['acctnum']==acctnum]['test'].cumsum()
    df['before']=1-df[df['acctnum']==acctnum]['after']
    r=df[df['acctnum']==acctnum]['after'].sum()-10
    df['test4']=(df[df['acctnum']==acctnum]['test3']-df[df['acctnum']==acctnum]['test2'])/2
    df['test5']=df[df['acctnum']==acctnum]['test4']+r
    df['new']=df['new']+df['test5'].fillna(0)
```

If there is a better faster way then I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: The 10 in line 7 was the middle number of data points per user, which I hard coded. This was very specific to my problem and was not meant to be general in any way.